# Run Activity with AlarmManager + Broadcast Receiver (on Redmi Note phones)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an Android app which opens an activity on a specific time with the help of AlarmManager and Broadcast Receiver.

The AlarmManager gets triggered on the desired time, Broadcast Receiver does get executed I have other code that runs just fine (such as sending the user a notification).

I want my `onReceive` method in my Broadcast Receiver to open an activity even if the app is not running. I'm fine with it opening something else too, as long as the user gets a screen of some sort in front of them.

Below approach works perfectly well on most phones. However, on Redmi Note devices primarily (and some Samsung devices) it does not seem to work, doesn't open the activity.

I have below code in `onReceive`

```
Intent in = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ShowAlarmActivity.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(in);
```

## - What I have setup/tried

1. I have given `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. doesn't work with that either. But this did fix it on a lot of Samsung devices I believe.
2. I have Auto-start enabled for the app.
3. I have Battery Optimization set to Unrestricted.
4. I Have tried setting a Component for the intent, as :

```
in.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), "com.example.mypackage.ShowAlarmActivity"));
```

5. Tried to open the activity through an action.

```
Intent in = new Intent("com.example.mypackage.ACTION_SHOW_NOW");
```

6. Tried flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

```
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

7. The `ShowAlarmActivity` has `exported` as `true` in `AndroidManifest`

```
android:exported="true"
```

Just as a reminder and as mentioned above, it works on majority of devices, I myself have **Xiaomi POCO F3** which it does work on it perfectly fine. Redmi Note phones are a set of phones that I have tried and got feedback from users that it does not work on it, which is also a Xiaomi brand.